# Auto Load content on scroll down using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've built a application [php] that loads content like text & images on scroll down automatically using ajax. The code works fine on `localhost`, but when i put it on my server it loads to slowly & sometimes the page dows not load at all or even loads all the content at once. Is there any alternative so I can overcome this issue?

Here's my code snippet that loads content from other page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var inc=5;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('body').height()-190 <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
    inc=inc+3;
        var dataString = inc;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "two.php",
            data: {'limit': dataString},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#a').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Assume the image size to be 100kb & the app loads 4-5 images on every scroll. Also the content comes from mysql databse through php & also the "two.php" file contains all the data that is being fetched. The `limit` variable is just used to set a limit to mysql query, i.e. how many rows are to be returned.

Comment: To better help you we would need some code snippets here...

Comment: Of course for any "ajaxy" stuff you need the server to be very responsive.

Comment: Very good question and interesting problem, but to overcome it there are many ways to do it, we basically need to identify the bottleneck first and work this out, we need much more details and code snippets, and perhaps the average size of images you're loading ? where they come from, and how the texts are fetched ? database/files, etc...

Comment: you can load all contents during page loading and then show partial content when scrolling.

Comment: Go to http://jscroll.com/ !